# Radio button selection to change state

Tags: reactjs

How do I set up an `input type="radio"` so that a state value will change depending on which the user select?

In this case, I want button `name="1"` to be the default selected button, but if button `name="2"` is selected by the user, some state value should change.

```
<div data-toggle="buttons">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="1" defaultChecked onChange={this.handleRadioButton}>Option 1</input>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="2" onChange={this.handleRadioButton}>Option 2</input>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `handleRadioButton` needs to be informed which button was clicked. I suggest a simple function parameter. i.e.

`onChange={() => this.handleRadioButton(1)}`

`onChange={() => this.handleRadioButton(2)}`

Your function might look like this:

```
handleRadioButton(value) {
  this.setState({
    value: value
  });
}
```

Finally, the checked state must be read from that state value. i.e.

`checked={this.state.value === 1}`

So putting it all together...

`<input
    type="radio"
    checked={this.state.value === 1}
    onChange={() => this.handleRadioButton(1)}
/>`

`<input
    type="radio"
    checked={this.state.value === 2}
    onChange={() => this.handleRadioButton(2)}
/>`

A couple more things:

- Don't bother with the `defaultChecked` property. Simply set `value: 1` in your initial state.
- No need for HTML attributes like `name` and `value`. In React, the HTML logic is superseded by JavaScript logic. (Caveat: Unless you're providing a server rendered non-JS fallback.)

Comment: Had a chance to try this out and unfortunately the `handleRadioButton` function never gets invoked. (I added a console.log to double-check) Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I would have to see how you defined your component. Please create a new post displaying the code.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348461/invoking-onchange-function-through-radio-button-selection

Comment: Saved me today! Thank you :)