# Invoking onChange function through radio button selection

Tags: reactjs

I would like to use a two-button toggle using radio buttons to register a state value (which I'll use to process the route the user will take after hitting the submit button).

```
var Pathfinder = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {query: '', pathname: '', route: 'one'};
  },
  handleRadioButton: function(type) {
    console.log('type: ', type);
    this.setState({route: type});
  },
  handleTextField: function(event) {
    if (this.state.route === 'one') {
      this.setState({pathname: '/pathone/'});
    } else {
      this.setState({pathname: '/pathtwo/'});
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input autoFocus type="search" onChange={this.handleTextField} />
            <div>
              <Link to={this.state.pathname}>
                <button type="submit"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div data-toggle="buttons">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" checked={this.state.route === 'one'} onChange={() => this.handleRadioButton('one')} />1
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" checked={this.state.route === 'two'} onChange={() => this.handleRadioButton('two')} />2
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
});
```

Running as above, the `onChange` function never gets invoked.

If I change the `onChange` anonymous function to:
`onChange={setTimeout( () => this.handleRadioButton('one'), 0)}` then it just rapidly changes back and forth from `one` to `two` ad infinitum.

Comment: your code is working fine. here is the fiddle link : -> https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36788/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention that I was using Bootstrap because I didn't think it was relevant...but it apparently was. There is a conflict between React and Bootstrap when it comes to certain input types, including radio buttons.

Switched to `react-bootstrap` and it's rendering just fine now - just have to fix some of the styling.

Comment: i ran into the same issue. it's `data-toggle` that's breaking the `onChange` listener