# ReactJS: How to set state of an object selected via radio button?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

In my `UsedComponents` component I have a list of mapped radio buttons that each return `componentType` as value.

```
this.props.usedComponents.map((component, index) => (
  <RadioButton
    key={index}
    id={component.componentType}
    icon={ButtonIco}
    label={component.componentName}
    name="select"
    value={component.componentType}
    inputClass={classes.RadioInput}
    labelClass={classes.RadioLabel}
    selected={component.selected}
    handleChange={this.props.selectComponent}
  />
))
```

My state looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    components: components,
    usedComponents: [components[0], components[2], components[3]],
  };
  this.selectComponentHandler = this.selectComponentHandler.bind(this);
}
```

`components` is an imported array of objects that each look something like this:

```
{
  componentType: "headerLogoNavigation",
  componentName: "Header 02",
  padding: "small",
  fontSize: "small",
  fontColor: "#1f1f1f",
  fontFamily: "Sans-serif",
  backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  image: placeholderLogo,
  selected: false,
  isEditing: false,
  margins: false,
  roundCorners: "none",
  mobile: "false"
}
```

In my `Page` component I'm trying to pass a `selectComponentHandler` prop to my `UsedComponents` component that should select a component based on a value of a selected radio button and set its state to `selected: true`. For an added bonus it should set the state of any previously selected component to `selected: false`.
So far I managed to figure out how to select the component but I'm not able to update its state. My final attempt to create this handler before I gave up looks like this:

```
selectComponentHandler = event => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let selected = prevState.usedComponents.filter(item => item.componentType === event.target.value);
    selected.selected = 'true';  
    return { selected };
  });
};
```

and it's an attempt to filter the `prevState` inside the `setState` for the `componentType` that matches `event.target.value` of the radio button and set it's state, but I messed up the logic or the syntax and my head is about to explode so I can't figure out what I did wrong.
Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for ? [Radio button selection to change state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345882/radio-button-selection-to-change-state)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not. My radio button returns componentType as value and I need to filter the objects inside the state for the one that matches the value and update its state to selected: true.

Comment: you can attach an onChange hander on your radio button.
```handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })```

Comment: Radio button value returns something like "headerLogoNavigation". I need to filter the usedComponents array inside the state for an object which has a componentType that matches, for example, "headerLogoNavigation". Each object also contains "selected: false" and this is what I need to update to true.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's a bit hacky but it works.

```
selectComponentHandler = event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let selected = prevState.usedComponents.filter(item => item.componentType === value).shift();
    let unSelected = prevState.usedComponents.filter(item => item.selected === true).shift();
    if(unSelected) {
      unSelected.selected = false;
    }
    selected.selected = true;  
    return { unSelected, selected };
  });
};
```

Comment: i think the setState should be kept as clean it can be. You can move out the logic written inside setState to some other function.